# bcrypt always returns false

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to store the hash password and checking the it is valid or not.

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
let data = "";

bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("my password", salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
        console.log(hash);
        data = hash;
    });
});

bcrypt.compare("my password", data, function(err, res) {
    // res === true
    console.log(res)
});
```

return value always false.?

but if I move the compare inside genSalt function its returning true.

Thanks

Comment: Because `data === ""`. Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with asynchronous functions in node.js, so this result is expected. For the clearer understanding of the problem try to `console.log` data before `bcrypt.compare`. I can certainly say it would be equal to an initial value of `""`.

Then try to move your compare function inside the `.hash` callback

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
let data = "";

bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("my password", salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
        console.log(hash);
        data = hash;
        console.log(data); // Here data equals to your hash
        bcrypt.compare("my password", data, function(err, res) {
            // res === true
            console.log(res)
        });
    });
});
console.log('data') // Here data equals to initial value of ""
```

You can use async/await functions to make it look like synchronous code and get rid of callbacks. Luckily, `bcrypt` support promise interface that is used by `async/await`

```
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hash = await bcrypt.hash("my password", salt);
const result = await bcrypt.compare("my password", data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This would be considered 'blocking', but could `bcrypt.compareSync` be used here?

Comment: @zer0kompression yes, but don't. It's a serious de-optimization that's no longer even syntactically advantageous with the addition of `async` / `await` to the ES7 specification.

Comment: Yes, I understand the asyn now. I was new to node.  Thanks. its working.

Comment: @zer0kompression Yes, it could and yes, you are right, it is a 'blocking' operation and you can access the result literally in the same line of code without using callbacks, but for the price of performance drawbacks.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you for pointing about undefined. Updated my post to fix it.

Comment: `const hash` -> `const data`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Okay, now I'm just being sloppy here. Thank you.